# How to build OpenAL-Soft and set up it in Qt Creator for Android

Tags: android, c++, qt, openal, openal-soft

I didn't find a step by step guide how to build OpenAL-Soft to use it from Qt for Android.

I tried to make it by copying OpenAL-Soft sources into a project. I copied the OpenAL-Soft sources into my example. You can download my example [here from DropBox](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/akqz27vozlpy3115cwh1l/openal-with-source-using-android-qt6-cpp.zip?rlkey=25hd2ln9enwclznw32uckwyrj&dl=0). I use Qt 6.2.4 and OpenAL-Soft 1.23.1. Please guys download the example archive. Try to compile. Who is more experienced will be able to understand the errors. My example contains the archive openal-soft-1.23.1.zip I will distribute the examples on the forums. It helps a lot to motivate beginners. OpenAL contains functions for working with 3D audio, and this is very attractive. Installing via adding library sources should be easy (apart from some nuances that should be documented), because Qt Creator has the wonderful "Add existing directories..." and "Add existing files..." options. If this topic is closed, then answer in the topic [at this link](https://forum.qt.io/topic/147990/how-to-install-openal-soft-in-qt-creator-by-copying-openal-soft-sources-into-a-project), or subscribe to it. I tried to build OpenAL-Soft for Android but I have these errors: https://github.com/DJLink/android-openal-soft/issues/1

I have already done this for Box2D and my app running on PC, emulator and android smartphone with the same codebase. This was the easiest and fastest way to install Box2D. I just copied the sources into the project and immediately switched between Android and Desktop to build APK and EXE. If I had included libraries, I would have spent a lot of time figuring out how to build for Android and how to switch between builds for Android and Desktop.

I can't ask a question on just one error because the errors can depend on each other. Perhaps someone also tried to add OpenAL-Soft to their project as sources and ran into the same errors.

[image]

Some of them:

```
In file included from ..\openal-with-source-using-android-qt6-cpp\core\converter.h:10,
                 from ..\openal-with-source-using-android-qt6-cpp\core\converter.cpp:4:
..\openal-with-source-using-android-qt6-cpp\core\mixer/defs.h:67:79: error: expected ',' or '...' before 'src'
   67 | using ResamplerFunc = void(*)(const InterpState *state, const float *RESTRICT src, uint frac,
      |                                                                               ^~~
..\openal-with-source-using-android-qt6-cpp\core\mixer/defs.h:74:64: error: expected ',' or '...' before 'src'
```

[image]

[image]

**Added later:**

I added `#define RESTRICT` and I see fewer errors. Some files have this line `#include "config.h"`, but this file is not in the OpenAL-Soft source code. I added the empty `config.h` file. I think this file must be generated by CMake if you are compiling OpenAL-Soft from source. I found the `config.h.in` file that doesn't have the `#define RESTRICT`:

config..h.in

```cpp
/* Define if deprecated EAX extensions are enabled */
#cmakedefine ALSOFT_EAX

/* Define if HRTF data is embedded in the library */
#cmakedefine ALSOFT_EMBED_HRTF_DATA

/* Define if we have the posix_memalign function */
#cmakedefine HAVE_POSIX_MEMALIGN

/* Define if we have the _aligned_malloc function */
#cmakedefine HAVE__ALIGNED_MALLOC

/* Define if we have the proc_pidpath function */
#cmakedefine HAVE_PROC_PIDPATH

/* Define if we have the getopt function */
#cmakedefine HAVE_GETOPT

/* Define if we have DBus/RTKit */
#cmakedefine HAVE_RTKIT

/* Define if we have SSE CPU extensions */
#cmakedefine HAVE_SSE
#cmakedefine HAVE_SSE2
#cmakedefine HAVE_SSE3
#cmakedefine HAVE_SSE4_1

/* Define if we have ARM Neon CPU extensions */
#cmakedefine HAVE_NEON

/* Define if we have the ALSA backend */
#cmakedefine HAVE_ALSA

/* Define if we have the OSS backend */
#cmakedefine HAVE_OSS

/* Define if we have the PipeWire backend */
#cmakedefine HAVE_PIPEWIRE

/* Define if we have the Solaris backend */
#cmakedefine HAVE_SOLARIS

/* Define if we have the SndIO backend */
#cmakedefine HAVE_SNDIO

/* Define if we have the WASAPI backend */
#cmakedefine HAVE_WASAPI

/* Define if we have the DSound backend */
#cmakedefine HAVE_DSOUND

/* Define if we have the Windows Multimedia backend */
#cmakedefine HAVE_WINMM

/* Define if we have the PortAudio backend */
#cmakedefine HAVE_PORTAUDIO

/* Define if we have the PulseAudio backend */
#cmakedefine HAVE_PULSEAUDIO

/* Define if we have the JACK backend */
#cmakedefine HAVE_JACK

/* Define if we have the CoreAudio backend */
#cmakedefine HAVE_COREAUDIO

/* Define if we have the OpenSL backend */
#cmakedefine HAVE_OPENSL

/* Define if we have the Oboe backend */
#cmakedefine HAVE_OBOE

/* Define if we have the Wave Writer backend */
#cmakedefine HAVE_WAVE

/* Define if we have the SDL2 backend */
#cmakedefine HAVE_SDL2

/* Define if we have dlfcn.h */
#cmakedefine HAVE_DLFCN_H

/* Define if we have pthread_np.h */
#cmakedefine HAVE_PTHREAD_NP_H

/* Define if we have malloc.h */
#cmakedefine HAVE_MALLOC_H

/* Define if we have cpuid.h */
#cmakedefine HAVE_CPUID_H

/* Define if we have intrin.h */
#cmakedefine HAVE_INTRIN_H

/* Define if we have guiddef.h */
#cmakedefine HAVE_GUIDDEF_H

/* Define if we have initguid.h */
#cmakedefine HAVE_INITGUID_H

/* Define if we have GCC's __get_cpuid() */
#cmakedefine HAVE_GCC_GET_CPUID

/* Define if we have the __cpuid() intrinsic */
#cmakedefine HAVE_CPUID_INTRINSIC

/* Define if we have SSE intrinsics */
#cmakedefine HAVE_SSE_INTRINSICS

/* Define if we have pthread_setschedparam() */
#cmakedefine HAVE_PTHREAD_SETSCHEDPARAM

/* Define if we have pthread_setname_np() */
#cmakedefine HAVE_PTHREAD_SETNAME_NP

/* Define if we have pthread_set_name_np() */
#cmakedefine HAVE_PTHREAD_SET_NAME_NP

/* Define the installation data directory */
#cmakedefine ALSOFT_INSTALL_DATADIR "@ALSOFT_INSTALL_DATADIR@"
```

Comment: Is there any reason you're adding the sources directly to your project, as opposed to building the libraries using their intended build systems?

Comment: Yes, I wrote about it in my question. As an example, I gave Box2D. This was the easiest and fastest way to install Box2D. I just copied the sources into the project and immediately switched between Android and Desktop to build APK and EXE. If I had included libraries, I would have spent a lot of time figuring out how to build for Android and how to switch between builds for Android and Desktop.

Comment: Investing time into that looks like a better option to me. You do it once, then every library will just work as is for you. Otherwise, for every remotely complex library, you'll need to figure out what unusual things the build system is doing, and replicate them somehow.

Comment: But I only need Box2D, OpenGL ES 2.0 (2.1 for desktop), and a sound library to make 2D games with Qt. Qt already has WebSockets, JSON, and so on. Now I see that the best solution in my case would be to use QMediaPlayer for the sounds. But in the future, I want to make 3D games with Bullet Physics. I will need 3D sound library. For now, I don't have to spend time on this. I'll spend my time later.

Comment: Note that OpenAL is LGPL-licensed. Which means you need to release the source to your application if you make it part of your application.

Comment: Please guys download the example archive. Try to compile. Who is more experienced will be able to understand the errors. My example contains the archive openal-soft-1.23.1.zip I will distribute the examples on the forums. It helps a lot to motivate beginners. OpenAL contains functions for working with 3D audio, and this is very attractive.

Comment: Honestly you're better off providing a framework such as [Glitter](https://github.com/Polytonic/Glitter) that automatically downloads and builds the dependencies as libraries. The less time wasted on accidental complexity the better.

Comment: I tried to build OpenAL-Soft for Android but I have these errors: https://github.com/DJLink/android-openal-soft/issues/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the simples way! I just downloaded these sources: https://github.com/AerialX/openal-soft-android and built it using CMake. The `libopenal.so` library was created. I created the "Play" button. I built my first app that plays music using OpenAL! It works on my smartphone! It's cool!

My step-by-step guide for Qt 6.2.4 MinGW 64-bit:

- Download these sources: https://github.com/AerialX/openal-soft-android
- Add CMake to the Path variable (CMake is distributed with Qt)
- Go to the `openal-soft-android-master` folder and open CMD there
- Copy the next commands to the console (don't forget to change the path to your `android.toolchain.cmake`)

> cmake -G "MinGW Makefiles" -S . -B ./build -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=E:\AppData\Android\SDK\ndk\25.1.8937393\build\cmake\android.toolchain.cmake -DANDROID_ABI=armeabi-v7a -DANDROID_NATIVE_API_LEVEL=25

> cmake --build ./build -j 4

The `libopenal.so` will be created. Create a new Qt project. Create the `jniLibs/armeabi-v7a` folder inside of your Qt project. And copy `libopenal.so` inside of `jniLibs/armeabi-v7a`.

Create the `libs\openal-soft\include` folder inside of your Qt project and copy the `AL` folder there.

Add these settings to your pro-file:

```
INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/libs/openal-soft/include

contains(ANDROID_TARGET_ARCH, armeabi-v7a)
{
    ANDROID_EXTRA_LIBS += $$PWD/jniLibs/armeabi-v7a/libopenal.so
}
```

**Added 1/14/2024**

I use these settings to run on Windows, real device, and Android Emulator:

```
CONFIG("windows") {
    INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/libs/openal-soft-desktop-1.23.1/include
    LIBS += -L$$PWD/libs/openal-soft-desktop-1.23.1/lib/x64
    LIBS += -lOpenAL32.dll
}

CONFIG("armeabi-v7a") {
    INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/libs/openal-soft-android/include
    contains(ANDROID_TARGET_ARCH, armeabi-v7a)
    {
        ANDROID_EXTRA_LIBS += $$PWD/jniLibs/armeabi-v7a/libopenal.so
    }
}

CONFIG("x86") {
    INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/libs/openal-soft-android/include
    contains(ANDROID_TARGET_ARCH, x86)
    {
        ANDROID_EXTRA_LIBS += $$PWD/jniLibs/x86/libopenal.so
    }
}
```